# Do important people and things look important?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Do primary objectives/people have a visual cue that lets you know you are about to embark on a major event (potentially missing uncompleted content)?

I know I can go reread my journal to figure out who I am supposed to be talking to but therein lies the dilemma. I tend to try collect all of the quests and events I can in one area before I go and attempt to complete ANY of them, the list can get pretty long. I then review the options I have and choose the missions I think will advance the story in the way I want. I don't want to start/complete missions on accident and preclude myself from other more interesting/in-character missions.

There are similar questions that deal with specific branching story lines and points of no return but I am wondering if any important people, major/minor quest givers, quest completion points, etc. LOOK different than one another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, important people and items stand out from the background.  If at any point you get lost, pressing the map button (on pc, this is <kbd>V</kbd>) can help find your way.  Additionally, important people in friendly areas (like the Citadel) are often talking over the crowd loud enough to catch players' attention.

While in a combat zone, this will highlight a point of interest such as a quest objective.

In a friendly area, it will bring up a map with all nearby people of interest listed)
[image: Map view]

Comment: The map hot key for the Xbox version is clicking the left thumbstick, if that's important.

Answer (score 0):

One of the biggest differences between Mass Effect 2 and 3 is that the distance that interactable items will start glowing (indicating thaty you can interact with them) is much reduced.

Dave has written a good answer when it comes to *finding* interactable objects, but I think I have a better idea for finding relevant conversations. (Sorry Dave :D )

Simply turn on Captions! Important conversations will show up as captions over the ambient noise, so it's easy to find out what's important and what can be safely ignored!